# Reverse string method with a linked list

Tags: java, list

My issue is reversing a linked list that is storing a string.  I know my method to reverse the linked list already works, I can use the same method to reverse a list of integers but it doesn't work when reversing a string. It gives me the following error and I'm not exactly sure why.

This is my printInReverse() method

```
public void printInReverse(Node L)
{
  if (L.next == null)
  {
     System.out.print(L.data + " ");
  }
  else
  {
     printInReverse(L.next);
     System.out.print(L.data + " ");
   }
}
```

Here is how I am calling the method

```
System.out.print("Reversed string: "); myList.printInReverse(myList.top);
```

Here is the error message I am receiving

```
ReverseString_Scott_Robinson.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.print("Reversed string: "); myList.printInReverse(myList.end);
                                             ^ 
symbol:   method 
printInReverse(Stack_Scott_Robinson<String>.Node<String>)
location: variable myList of type Stack_Scott_Robinson<String>
Note: ReverseString_Scott_Robinson.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

Comment: Can you show the code before the `System.out.print("Reversed string: ");` line? And also can you show the whole `Stack_Scott_Robinson` class?

Comment: you can provide code for whole program.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to call your method on the List object. This interface does not have a printInReverse function so this is an error. just call the function like so:

```
printInReverse(myList.top);
```

as opposed to:

```
myList.printInReverse(myList.top);
```